# How to find relative frequency of values greater than x, x+10000 in a big dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 1 million rows and 10 columns where each observation can have a value from 0 to 100 million (upper bound not set, but it can't go to infinity). I need to find relative frequency of values greater than x, x+10000. The dataframe looks something like this:

```
     Event1       Event2    Event3...

1     0.00        10320.21   1400.0

2     143212.31   0.00       0.00

3     0.00        32573.77   0.00

4     0.00        0.00       3582774.87

5     3403.14     0.00       14754.50

...
```

I have made a code that shows me the desired results but it would take hours to input all the different values I want.

```
relative.percent <- function(x, n){ 100*length((which(x > n))) / length(x) }

relative.percent(results$Event1,10000)
```

I want to get the relative percentage of values greater than 0 with an interchangeable interval of lets say 10000.

So that the output is a list or table that would show me the percentage of values from  a  column (Event 1, Event 2 ...) that are greater than 0, and values that are greater than 10000  and the relative percentage of values greater than 20000 and and so on all they way to the max value of the dataset (which could be 100 million)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if I understood you correctly you want to learn some kind of empirical cumulative distribution. You should look up how to use apply, it will make you life much easier.

Code below needs some time to learn, but then your look-ups should be relatively fast. So if you want percentage of values that are LESS or EQUAL to query for specific column, you just pass a vector of values then get back a vector of percentages. If you want to condition, there is example below.

Hope it helps.

```
library(dplyr) ## just for %>% 
test <- data.frame(x1=rpois(100,n = 10**7),x2=rpois(100,n = 10**7),
                   x3=rpois(100,n = 10**7),x4=rpois(100,n = 10**7),
                   x5=rpois(100,n = 10**7),x6=rpois(100,n = 10**7),
                   x7=rpois(100,n = 10**7),x8=rpois(100,n = 10**7),
                   x9=rpois(100,n = 10**7),x10=rpois(100,n = 10**7)
                   )
system.time({
  get_function <- apply(test,2,ecdf)
  ## learning fucntion 10 million instances, 10 rows
  ##user  system elapsed 
  ##4.38    0.73    5.16 
})

evaluate <- function(query,funct=get_function){
  lapply(1:length(get_function),function(i){
    funct[[i]](query[i])
  }) %>% unlist()
}

query_1 <- rep(-10,10) ## never appear, percentage should be 0
query_2 <- rep(100,10) ## around 0.5
query_3 <- rep(10000,10) ## 1 or close to 1



evaluate(query_1)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
evaluate(query_2)
# [1] 0.526348 0.526626 0.526714 0.526150 0.527456 0.526217 0.525491 0.526729 0.526429 0.525340
evaluate(query_3)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

## get percentage of values between 95 and 100
query_4 <- rep(95,10)
evaluate(query_2) - evaluate(query_4)
#[1] 0.1954705 0.1952166 0.1952291 0.1954930 0.1955171 0.1954126 0.1952673 0.1953782 0.1952068 0.1953201
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I need obviously need to take a look at apply functions :) 

With apply I would be able to create an output that shows for example 

percentage of observations with value of 10.000+ = 10.62% 

20,000+ = 8.73 %

...
1,500,000+ = 3.43% 

and so on

so that i can graph an (inverted?) cumulative frequency graph

Comment: @Cova You can just plot the ecdf or plot 1- ecdf. Use plot(get_function[[i]]). If I answered your question please accept it. :)